# Can someone explain to me whats happening in this code step by step, c++

Tags: c++

I mean only main function. I dont understand int(c) when(when is not part of the code) c is char. How doeas it work?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 char c;
 cout << "Enter a character: ";
 cin >> c;
 cout << "ASCII Value of " << c << " is " << int(c);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please open your text-book on the chapter or section about *conversions* and *type casting*.

Comment: It converts the char to an integer using the char's *encoding*, and then outputs the integer. The bit about `ASCII` is a bug, C++ doesn't require the use of ASCII.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a table(the ASCII table), which stores a map from int to char(this is how chars are represented). The ASCII value of a char is actually the int key of that char in this table. Casting a char into int - `int(c)` - gives you this int key(ASCII Value of c).